# Using Yii relational query

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

Is it possible while defining a related Model in an ActiveRecord definition to specify a relation scope that allows only those models to be related whose corresponding column(s) match some predefined critaria in the joining table ?

eg. let us have a users table with fields : id(pk), username(pk),pwd_hash(text), pwd_salt(text)

and an items table : id(pk), itemData(text)

and a correlating table : id(pk),user_id(pk), item_id(pk), some_attribute(int)

Now I would like to define a Many-to-Many relationship such that User Model has a field xitems which would provide me only those items for which the value of some_attribute is greater than some value y. Is it possible to do so using Yii ActiveRecord implementation.

I do understand that I can define a model corresponding to the correlating table which would have belongs-to relation with both items and users and query this table ... but I was looking for a more succinct approach. 
[edit]

Probably my best bet would be define a model method which abstracts an inner join operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure you do need a model for the join table to get access to its data, which your example needs. Without the join table model, AR will only deal with the FKs in the join table (AFAIK).

This article may be of help to you: [Accessing data in a join table with the related models](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/285/accessing-data-in-a-join-table-with-the-related-models)